# Linkerror undefined symbol: __aeabi_uldivmod

Tags: c, micropython

I'm trying to add module native on micropython.
I get the following output:

```
LINK build_file/Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f7xx_hal_tim.o
LinkError: build_file/Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f7xx_hal_rcc.o: undefined symbol: __aeabi_uldivmod
make: *** [../py/dynruntime.mk:144: build_file/ethernet.native.mpy] Error 1
```

Comment: A compiler sometimes generates symbols for operations for which it has no native instruction. If you then link the object code for another platform, these symbols may not be present in the target libraries. You can extract these symbols (functions) from the original libraries and link them with your target libraries.

Comment: Thank you, but how to do that ?

Comment: could you provide the command line (s) that produce this error?

Comment: # Build native .mpy from object files
$(BUILD)/$(MOD).native.mpy: $(SRC_O)
 $(ECHO) "LINK $<"
 $(Q)$(MPY_LD) --arch $(ARCH) --qstrs $(CONFIG_H) -o $@ $^

Comment: MPY_LD = $(PYTHON) $(MPY_DIR)/tools/mpy_ld.py